# Only deleting the oldest element created using jQuery, after a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ship fly over whenever a button is clicked, although at the moment it deletes all of the the ships on screen, not the oldest one created.

```
(function (el) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    el.children().remove('.ship');
  }, 5000);
}($('#saleShipHolder').append("<div class='ship' id='saleShip'></div>")));
```

It creates the ship, appends the ship element but the problem arises when the ship gets removed as it removes all of them on screen, not the oldest one. Sorry as I find this difficult to explain.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: `el.find('.ship').first().remove()`?

Comment: is there any pattern in the markup where the ship you want to delete is? for example, are you adding ships top to bottom? if so, the top would be the "oldest" and you could delete with `el.find('.ship').first().remove()` or something similar

Comment: Thankyou, that has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not encapsulate the ship ?

```
(function (el) {
    var ship = $("<div class='ship' id='saleShip'></div>");

    el.append(ship);

    setTimeout(function () {
      ship.remove();
    }, 5000);

}($('#saleShipHolder')));
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the ship to automatically remove itself, I think the removal is only required after another ship is added.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, each "ship" has the same id, which it should not have. Also since they all have the same class, its going to find them all.

A simple approach would be to `splice` the newest ship element onto an array,and on your timeout `.pop()` off the oldest entry, and remove it .